# Prevent Status Bar Appearance From Dialog Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, statusbar

I have a pretty standard Dialog call. The problem is it brings up the status bar and I hide it when they click OK. Do you know how I can prevent the status bar from appearing when the dialog is shown?

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics

    builder.setMessage("Please fill in the missing blocks in this layout with photos or choose a different layout.")
                                        .setTitle("Missing Photos");

                                // Add the buttons

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
  {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
      {
        hideSystemUI();
      }
  });

     // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.show();
```

Comment: Could you use dialog.setOnShowListener(...) to call hideSystemUI() when the dialog is shown?

Comment: I tried and the status bar still appears.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are hiding the title bar programmatically for your activities and fragments while the dialog still inherits the theme you have set for the app and that theme doesn't hide the title bar. All you need to do is to simple specify a custom theme for your dialog in styles.xml and then set your dialogs theme to it in code. Here is an example

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="AppTheme"> 
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now in your code set the custome theme on the dialog like this

```
dialog.setStyle( DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
```

Comment: You can't set the style on a dialog you have to set it on the builder. Setting a theme also makes the dialog take up the entire screen.